# $ne doesn't work with pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo, mongodb-query

my `$ne : ""` is not working properly with pymongo.

```
hashtable['ACR-WEB-01']=db.logs.find({"host_name" : "WEB-01"}, {"service_description": {"$ne" : ""}}).distinct("service_description")
print hashtable['ACR-WEB-01']
```

The result of the print is :

```
[u'Disks', u'', u'Mem', u'VM Tools', u'Cpu', u'vm-alarm-CPU', u'vm-alarm-MEM', u'vm-alarm-VMTOOLS', u'Uptime']
```

As you can see, i get `u''` why?

If i execute this directly in mongodb, it works :

```
> db.logs.distinct( "service_description" , { "host_name" : "WEB-01", service_description: {$ne : ""}} )
[
    "Cpu",
    "Disks",
    "Mem",
    "Uptime",
    "VM Tools",
    "vm-alarm-CPU",
    "vm-alarm-MEM",
    "vm-alarm-VMTOOLS"
]
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put both of your `find` query terms into the *same* hash object:

```
hashtable['ACR-WEB-01']=db.logs
    .find({"host_name": "WEB-01", "service_description": {"$ne" : ""}})
    .distinct("service_description")
```